# I want to store diffrent type of values in same index of arraylist and store the in diffrent class method

Tags: java, arraylist, model-view-controller

I have two class in class Flight there is get and set value method and another class i have created a arraylist in which i want to create a database of all flights which contains name,location and time of flight and want to set that value in class Flight method setname. When i run this below code i got an error that "cannot find symbol" in class Model line: `flights.add(new Flight.setname("xyz"));`
class 2:

First cl

```
public class Flight {

private String name;
private String location;
private int time;





    public String getname()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setname(String name)
    {
        this.name= name;
    }


    public String getlocation()
    {
        return location;
    }

    public void setlocation(String location)
    {
        this.location= location;
    }


    public int getime()
    {
        return time;
    }

    public void settime(int time)
    {
        this.time = time;
    }


    }



}
```

Second class

```
import java.util.*;

public class Model {


private  ArrayList<Flight> flight = new ArrayList<Flight>(); 

public void flights()

{
    
    flight.add(new Flight.setname("xyz"));
}





}
```

Comment: Please explain what you expect `flight.add(new Flight.setname("xyz"));` to do. I think you have some misconceptions.

Comment: i want to make an array[0] = (name, location, time) array[1] = (name, location, time) this array represent diffrent flight information and want to store that value in diffrent class (Flight). i expect that "xyz" string store in a setname(Srting) method and in array as well

Comment: there is no such thing in Java array[0] = (name, location, time). an array of Flight items only accepts (can add) Flight objects

Answer (score 0):

the problems with your code:

1. the call to constructor is missing parenthesis `new Flight()`
2. the setter method `setname("xyz")` is defined as returning void. so you are trying to add "void" to the array list.

there is actually a design pattern that allows to construct new instance of `Flight`, populate its properties (instance variables) and add the instance to the array list: [The builder pattern](https://howtodoinjava.com/design-patterns/creational/builder-pattern-in-java/)

here is a demonstration of the pattern with one property

```
public class Flight {

    private String name;
    private String location;
    private int time;

    public Flight withName(String name) {
        setName(name);
        return this;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public static Flight newFlight() {
        return new Flight();
    }

}

flight.add(newFlight().withName("xyz")...);
```